# how to fix multipage form display and functionality issues in internet explorer?

Tags: jquery, css, forms, internet-explorer

i am working on this form:

http://jsfiddle.net/pPWr3/14/

which is displaying ok in chrome and firefox but has display and functionality issues in internet explorer 9:

- 'back' and 'next' page functionality does not work.
- 'back' and 'next' buttons appear on first page of form.
- all pages are displayed on top of one another on the front page.
- javascript onblur effects do not work.

can anyone suggest ways i can troubleshoot this or provide a jsfiddle version that works in ie?

thank you.

the scripts used are a modified version hosted on github of:

- https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-multipage-form

and:

- https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

and the relevant multipage script is:

```
//jquery multipage behaviour
$('#multipage').multipage({transitionFunction:transition, 
'navigationFunction': function(pages){},
'inactiveDot': '<img src="http://dummyimage.com/10x10/cccccc/cccccc.png" style="margin-right: 5px">',
'activeDot': '<img src="http://dummyimage.com/10x10/c27daf/c27daf.png" style="margin-right: 5px">'
});

// progresses user to next page on clicking option one or two on the front page
$("#option1, #option2").click( function(){        

$('#multipage').nextpage();  

});
// handles previous/next page click
$('.multipage_back').click(function(){            
$('#multipage').prevpage();
});
$('.multipage_next').click(function(){
if(!validate())  return false;
$('#multipage').nextpage();                        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was that the scripts were hosted on github gist and for some reason the form only worked in ie when the scripts were placed instead on different hosting.